# i cant display a paragraph in TextView

Tags: android

i put a paragraph in string.xml file it works fin in the preview but i have the problem in my phone 
[the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DECid.jpg)

[my phone :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhT2N.jpg)

code snipte:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="@string/intro"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#ff867c"
            android:onClick="droitObjectif"
            android:text="droit objectif"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thank you evreyone

Comment: Did you escape ' from your string xml? for example s\'il

Comment: oh yeah u right ill try the \